# Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.String[]'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, exception

why this line:

```
var category = _dataContext.Categories.Where<Category>(p => p.Keywords.Split(' ').Contains<string>(context.Request.QueryString["q"])).First();
```

throws an System.NotSupportedException:

> Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.String[]'

And how can I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

So you are looking for a value (from the query-string) in a space-delimited column in the database? And you're using `Split` to query the individual values inside the database?

(just checking my assumptions...)

`string.Split` is not supported in this way (at the database on column data) - see here for the [supported string operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882672.aspx). (note that `string.Split` is *explicitly* not supported).

I'm lazy; when I delimit data in the database (relatively rare), I always add the same delimiter to the start and end of the data; then I can just search for:

```
string searchFor = DELIMITER + searchValue + DELIMITER;
...
.Where(row => row.Value.Contains(searchFor));
```

However; in this case, I expect the most practical option might be to write a UDF function that searches a delimited `varchar` (correctly handling the first/last item), and expose the UDF on the data-context - then use:

```
.Where(row => ctx.ContainsValue(row.Value, searchValue)); // ContainsValue is our UDF
```

Or - normalise the data...

```
.Where(row => row.Values.Any(s=>s.Value == searchValue));
```

Answer (score 3):

`string.split` is not supported in LINQ-to-SQL.

There's an easy fix. Select all the data and do the filtering in the client. This may not be very efficient depending on the number of categories.

```
var category = 
    _dataContext.Categories.ToList()
    .Where<Category>(p => p.Keywords.Split(' ').Contains<string>(context.Request.QueryString["q"])).First();
```

Calling `.ToList()` will force enumeration of all the categories from your datasource, and the subsequent operations will be performed in the client code.

Comment: Reading the entire table back to the client is almost always a bad idea. There are some cases where it works, but they are the strict minority.

Comment: Indeed, it can be a huge performance hit but one must weigh this against the commonly held belief that pre-optimization is also bad. As well as large scale projects where this would be a problem, there are probably countless little web applications out there where the performance hit for this scenario would be trivial. I guess it just comes down to common sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the case that `context.Request.QueryString["q"]` returns a string array instead of a single string. This is because a url may contain multiple parameters with the same name.

If you are sure there is always just one parameter named q on the request, you can change your code to this: `context.Request.QueryString["q"].SingleOrDefault()`.

Comment: Just checked - it doesn't. It returns "q1,q2,q3,q4,q5" as a string, not an array.

Comment: HttpRequest.QueryString is a NameValueCollection.

Comment: Indexer of NameValueCollection returns string -_-

Comment: Actually - i thought the same. But checked before posting. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd avoid storing delimited data in the database. As you've found out it can make database queries etc awkward.

If you have a limit amount of categories, I'd go with Joe's answer for simplicity, else, adding some detail to Marc's approach.

1. Create a split-style UDF, for SQL Server I use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_CHARLIST_TO_TABLE
 (@list      nvarchar(MAX),
  @delimiter nchar(1) = N',')
RETURNS @tbl TABLE (listpos int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
              str     varchar(4000)      NOT NULL,
              nstr    nvarchar(2000)     NOT NULL) AS
/*                
  Comments:
        - Takes a CSV string, and creates a table of data from this
        - Each item takes one row in the following format
            listpos - the index of the item in the string (effectively a row number in the output)
            str - The value, as VARCHAR
            nstr - The value, as NVARCHAR

        - This function is a direct extract from http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#iter-list-of-strings
Usage:
    SELECT * 
    FROM  t 
    JOIN FN_CHARLIST_TO_TABLE('a,b,c,1,2,3', ',') list
    ON t.Name = list.str        
*/
BEGIN
   DECLARE @endpos   int,
       @startpos int,
       @textpos  int,
       @chunklen smallint,
       @tmpstr   nvarchar(4000),
       @leftover nvarchar(4000),
       @tmpval   nvarchar(4000)

   SET @textpos = 1
   SET @leftover = ''
   WHILE @textpos  0
      BEGIN
     SET @tmpval = ltrim(rtrim(substring(@tmpstr, @startpos + 1,
                         @endpos - @startpos - 1)))
     INSERT @tbl (str, nstr) VALUES(@tmpval, @tmpval)
     SET @startpos = @endpos
     SET @endpos = charindex(@delimiter COLLATE Slovenian_BIN2,
                 @tmpstr, @startpos + 1)
      END

      SET @leftover = right(@tmpstr, datalength(@tmpstr) / 2 - @startpos)
   END

   INSERT @tbl(str, nstr)
      VALUES (ltrim(rtrim(@leftover)), ltrim(rtrim(@leftover)))
   RETURN
END
```

2. Add this to your DBML file
3. Query your database, referencing the UDF appropriately

```
var catergories = from cat in _datacontext.Categories
                  from keyword in _datacontext.FN_CHARLIST_TO_TABLE(cat.Keywords, ' ')
                  where keyword.str == context.Request.QueryString["q"]
                  select cat;
```

This will then execute a purely database-side query.

Answer (score -2):

1)  ToList() your var query

2) In generated list in 1 step write your contain and split query: it execute correctly

good luck