# How to use LINQ to SQL to create ranked search results?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, search, full-text-search

I am looking for a way to use l2s to return ranked result based on keywords.

I would like to take a keyword and be able to search the table for that keyword using `.contains()`. The trick that I haven't been able to figure out is how to get a count of how many times that keyqord appears, and then `.OrderByDescending()` based on that count.

So if i had some thing like:

```
string keyword = "SomeKeyword";

IQueryable<Article> searchResults = from a in GenesisRepository.Article
                                    where a.Body.Contains(keyword)
                                    select a;
```

What is the best way to order `searchResults` based on the number of times `keyword` appears in `a.Body`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It appears that this cannot be done with .Split() and Regex because they don't exist in LINQ to SQL. Still looking for a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try inserting `order by a.Body.Split(' ').Count(w=>w == keyword)`. That should allow you to see that the concept works. However, I STRONGLY recommend that the final version include this as part of the select projection, possibly using a key-value pair, and order by the property name:

```
string keyword = "SomeKeyword";

//EDIT: restructured query to force the ordering to be done on the projection, 
//not the source.
IQueryable<Article> searchResults = (from a in GenesisRepository.Article
                                    where a.Body.Contains(keyword)
                                    select new KeyValuePair<int, Article>(
                                       a.Body.Split(' ').Count(w=>w == keyword), a))
                                    .OrderBy(kvp=>kvp.Key);
```

The reason is performance; the Split().Count() method chain is linear-complexity, and will be evaluated for every comparison of two values, making the overall sort N^2logN complexity (slow).

EDIT: Also, understand that a.Body.Contains(keyword) will not search by whole words, and so will return articles that contain "SomeKeywordLongerThanSearch" and "ThisIsSomeKeyword" as well as "SomeKeyword". You can avoid this with a Regex match on the pattern "\bSomeKeyword\b", which will only match instances of SomeKeyword with a word boundary immediately before and after.

Comment: I'm getting an error on `KeyValuePair` and the `order by Key`. Where is `Key` defined? <br />`Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>' requires 2 type arguments`<br />

Comment: I also realizing that my question may be flawed. I don't think this would handle multiple keywords... ie: "This is a string of keywords"

Comment: To make the ordering behave, you may need to surround the from, where, and select clauses of the query in one set of parenthesis; this will force the compiler to evaluate that part first, THEN sort, instead of putting the Order By in wherever it thinks will be most performant. Then, replace `new KeyValuePair` with `new KeyValuePair<int, Article>` or whatever a's type is. I had thought that the constructor could infer the types like a generic method can; I was wrong.

Comment: It compiles now but for some reason, when I run the query and then try a `foreach` on the KVP it fails. When I put a breakpoint on `searchResults` I drill into it and found this: {"Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.String[]'."}

Comment: After looking into this a bit... apparently .Split() is not supported in linqTOsql (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211942/comparison-operators-not-supported-for-type-system-string)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hack I came up with, pretty simple but definitely not a "best practices" one.

```
IQueryable<Article> searchResults = from a in GenesisRepository.Article
                       where a.Body.Contains(keyword)
                       orderby a.Body.Split(new string[] { keyword }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count() descending
                       select a;
```

Comment: Method 'System.String[] Split(System.String[], System.StringSplitOptions)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: By the solutions provided here, I would conclude that you need to make a sql server function or bringing the whole table back to the client and then performing the orderby. Go for the function or store proc.

Comment: Yeah... that's kinda what i figured. too bad. I hate needing to get an entire result set and then perform sub queries on it with function which is what I'll have to do if there is ever a need for pagination. Time to go talk to the sql programmer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work...

```
IQueryable<Article> searchResults = from a in GenesisRepository.Article
                                        where a.Body.Contains(keyword)
                                        select a;

searchResults.OrderByDescending(s => Regex.Matches(a.Body, keyword).Count);
```

Comment: Threw this error: `Method 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection Matches(System.String, System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL. 
`

Comment: Right, I moved the ordering out of the linq to sql call. Try it now.