# Convert SQL to LINQ for same table query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been trying to write a linq query but the groupby performance is horrifically slow, so I wrote my query in SQL instead and it's really speady but I can't get linq pad to convert it to linq for me. Can any body help me convert this sql to Linq please:

```
(SELECT mm.rcount, * FROM
(SELECT m.TourID AS myId, COUNT(m.RecordType) AS rcount FROM
(
((SELECT *
FROM Bookings h
WHERE h.RecordType = 'H' AND h.TourArea like '%bull%')
union
(SELECT *
FROM Bookings t
WHERE t.RecordType = 'T' and t.TourGuideName like '%bull%'))
) m
group by m.TourID) mm
INNER JOIN Bookings b ON mm.myId= b.TourID
WHERE b.RecordType = 'H');
```

here's my LINQ effort but it takes like 20 seconds to iterate over 200 records:

```
        var heads = from head in db.GetTable<BookingType>()
                    where head.RecordType == "H" &&
                    head.TourArea.Contains("bull")
                    select g;

        var tgs = from tourguides in db.GetTable<BookingType>()
                  where tourguides.RecordType == "T" &&
                  tourguides.TourGuideName.Contains("bull")
                  select tourguides;

        var all = heads.Union(tgs);
        var groupedshit = from r in all
                          group r by r.BookingID into g
                          select g;

        return heads;
```

**Edit 1:**
Here's my database structure:

BookingID [PK] | TourID | RecordType | TourArea | TourGuideName | ALoadOfOtherFields

And here's some sample data:

1 | 1 | H | Bullring | null

2 | 1 | T | null     | Bulldog

3 | 2 | H | Bullring | null

4 | 2 | T | null     | Bulldog

5 | 2 | T | null     | bull stamp

There will only ever be a single H (head) record but could potentially have many T (tour guide) records. After the grouping if I select a new (like this question: [How to use LINQ to SQL to create ranked search results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585995/how-to-use-linq-to-sql-to-create-ranked-search-results)) on the .Contains('bull') with a .Count() I can then get ranked searching (which is the whole point of this exercise).

**Edit 2:**
I've added in a property for search rank in the class itself to avoid the problem of then converting my results into a key/value pair. I don't know if this is best practice but it works.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Search Ranking
    /// </summary>
    public int? SearchRank { get; set; }
```

and then I execute a SQL query directly using linq-to-sql:

```
        IEnumerable<BookingType> results = db.ExecuteQuery<BookingType>
        ("(SELECT  mm.rcount AS SearchRank, b.* FROM (SELECT m.TourID AS myId, COUNT(m.RecordType) AS rcount FROM (((SELECT * FROM Bookings h WHERE h.RecordType = 'H' AND h.TourArea like '%{0}%') union (SELECT * FROM Bookings t WHERE t.RecordType = 'T' and t.TourGuideName like '%{0}%')) ) m group by m.TourID) mm INNER JOIN Bookings b ON mm.myId= b.TourID WHERE b.RecordType = 'H')", "bull");
```

I can add in as many 'AND's and 'OR's as I like now without Linq-to-sql going mental (the query it generated was a crazy 200 lines long!

Ranked Search viola!

Comment: Any particular reason you're returning `heads` instead of `groupedshit`? Just seems like you setup your query just to do a select on `Bookings` type for `RecordType = 'H' AND TourArea LIKE '%bull%'`.

Comment: Why do you use union against simple or? And what do you want to get with this query?

Comment: @SPFireDrake lol, I forgot I left 'groupedshit' in there. I do actually want to return the grouped shit (once it works).

Comment: @Kirill I use a union on a simple or because when I use the group keyword my query time just goes through the roof.

Comment: @Smithy The problem is that ROW_NUMBER isn't supported in L2S, so there's no way to really get the values you're looking for. I think HLGEM's solution is probably your only option, as you're trying to get "ranked" results which is not always possible with L2S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother converting it? You can just call the SQl you have opptimized.

Comment: `            IEnumerable<BookingType> results = db.ExecuteQuery<BookingType>
            ("(SELECT  mm.rcount AS SearchRank, b.* FROM (SELECT m.TourID AS myId, COUNT(m.RecordType) AS rcount FROM (((SELECT * FROM Bookings h WHERE h.RecordType = 'H' AND h.TourArea like '%{0}%') union (SELECT * FROM Bookings t WHERE t.RecordType = 'T' and t.TourGuideName like '%{0}%')) ) m group by m.TourID) mm INNER JOIN Bookings b ON mm.myId= b.TourID WHERE b.RecordType = 'H')", "bull");
`... many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `union` at all. you can use `Where OR AND` something like this should work:

```
 var result=    from b in DB.GetTable<Booking>()
                where (b.recordType =="H" || b.recordType=="T") 
                       &&b.TourArea.Contains("bull")
                group b by b.Booking_Id into g
                select g;
```

Comment: Except the `RecordType = "H"` is conditional on `TourArea` and `RecordType  ="T"` is conditional on `TourGuideName`. Still, this can easily be modified to `where (b.RecordType == "T" && b.TourGuideName.Contains("bull")) || (b.RecordType == "H" && b.TourArea.Contains("bull"))`. However, splitting and unioning them together is sometimes faster, because it's able to utilize different indexes for each of the subqueries, so it really just depends on how his table is set up (indexed).

Comment: @SPFiredrake, you're right I didn't notice that one condition uses TourGuideName and other uses TourArea.

Comment: I know but once I've added all my other search fields into the search my query time skyrockets and my WCF service won't execute it before returning an error about the function taking too long.