# Comparison operators not support for 'System.String[]' in a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm working on a Linq query to join data from two tables (using Linq to SQL), with the logic as follows:

- Banners contains a field which has comma separated values in it.  I want to split this column and have a list of IDs (for example 1,2,3,4)
- References contains a list of these mappings with 1:1 mapping between the ID in banners and the ID in the reference table
- Once the tables are merged I want to return the description from the reference table, which is the text representation of the ID.

I've been fiddling with this for a while and have hit a brick wall.  Below is the code I am using (in LinqPad):

```
var results = (from b in Banners
         where b.BannerCode == "1234"
         from a in b.VesselBoatAreaY.Split (',').AsEnumerable()
         join r in References on a equals r.ReferenceCode
         where r.Context == "TestContext" 
         select r.Description).ToList();
```

I have confirmed that the first part of the query works, i.e. that banner code exists and returns 4 separate values.  When I run the query as a whole however I get the following:

> NotSupportedException 
>   Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.String[]'.

I have also tried the following:

```
var results = (from b in Banners
               where b.BannerCode == "1234"
               from a in b.VesselBoatAreaY.Split (',').AsEnumerable()
               from r in References
               where r.Context == "TestContext" &&
               a.Contains(r.ReferenceCode)
               select r.Description).ToList();
```

When I run this I get the following:

> ArgumentException
>   The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'System.String'. Actual 'System.String[]'.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You **cannot** use .NET methods in Linq and expect them to 'just work' when EF tries to create a SQL query. It is a very specific set of methods that **can** be translated. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi, I should have said - I'm not using EF, I'm using LinqToSQL.  I avoid EF for that exact reason.

Comment: The same applies to LinqToSql, or any other LINQ provider.

Comment: What is stopping you from writing this query in SQL?

Comment: @mayer06 I am trying to avoid anything like a stored procedure - I want to do this in C#

Comment: @marteen, I'd disagree - there are various things I can do in linqtosql (for example .ToString() ) which are not supported in EF.

Comment: While your question is much more detailed, I believe this is your answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211942/comparison-operators-not-supported-for-type-system-string

Comment: @Andrew I'm sure there are things LinqToSql supports, and EF doesn't, and vice versa. The point is that you shouldn't expect every .NET method to be usable when writing Linq queries.

Comment: Are you aware that by using `AsEnumerable` you are switching the context from LINQ to SQL back to LINQ to objects? Which pretty much means anything run *after* that call is all happening in memory (not sure how that affects the joins).

Comment: @James.  Please see my answer below.  Yes, I was aware of the AsEnumerable memory restrictions, but as the tables are pretty small it's not a huge consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones help.  I've solved the problem and it was actually very easy.  As the table I am reading from is quite small I can apply AsEnumerable to the Banners table and it works fine.  I realise this means it will get processed in memory, so it's not good for bigger tables, but its fine for what I need.

For reference the code is now:

```
var results = (from b in Banners.AsEnumerable()
               where b.BannerCode == "1234"
               from a in b.VesselBoatAreaY.Split (',')
               from r in References.AsEnumerable()
               where r.Context == "TestContext" &&
               a.Contains(r.ReferenceCode)
               select r.Description).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm surprised this works because L2S doesn't [support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882672%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) `String.Split`. My guess is the `AsEnumerable` call switches the context of the join before it's executed (which is even more strange because it's called *after* `Split`). I'd be interested in what the SQL for this query looks like.

Comment: I've ran it through SQL profiler and it reads in the banner stuff first and then all the reference stuff as a separate query, so it seems to be just loading it into memory and processing it there.

Comment: Ah, just realised you have `AsEnumerable` on the `Banners` part - that makes sense. If you try it without that does it still work?

Comment: This means you are completely loading the mentioned tables from the database, and do any processing in-memory. The VesselBoatAreaY is probably lazily loaded.

Comment: @James, no it doesn't.  It appears the AsEnumerable is critical to it working.

Comment: @Andrew yep that's because like I said `Split`/`Contains` aren't supported by LINQ to SQL, what you are effectively doing here is taking the entire table into memory and performing everything client-side, is `References` a DB table as well?